# How to 'Stream' large data using WCF 4.5 WebSockets

Tags: wcf, stream, websocket

I was looking into the new **WCF 4.5 Websocket services**. 
Ran into trouble while making calls to the service via browser.

As it turns out (after alot of googling stuff), when you're dealing with web browser as a client for your web-sockets, the only way WCF 4.5 will work is, if you define your **OperationContract** with '**Action="*"**' **tag** [as there is no explicit way to call a 'specific' function from the browser, you can just call 'ws.send("asd")' to send messages to the server, hence you need to define a single handler for all the incomming calls to the service, similarly there can only be one callback function]

Now, if you use **'Action="*"'** you can only use the datatype '**Message**' while defining your contracts.

This is well and good, if you want to create an echo server, but lets say, you want to upload/download data, in the default (buffered) mode, the data transfer speeds are not what they are supposed to be (20mb file takes 40-50 secs). The only way to improve the speeds is by setting the mode as '**Streamed**' (i tried using '**StreamResponse**').

But now the trouble is, since we can only use '**Message**' as the datatype *while defining the Contracts*, and Message uses SOAP type def., it uses the '**Buffered**' mode, even if its explicitly defined otherwise. [please correct me if i am wrong here]

So, my question is, is there any way to achieve, 'streamed data transfer' in WCF 4.5 Websockets.

And, yes i am using byteStreamMessageEncoding (latest one provided in 4.5).
And i am using 'custom binding' in the web.config as '**netHttpBinding**' doesnt work with browsers.

Comment: WebSockets does framing to messages, and it is Message based protocol but not Stream based, even if it is actually based on TCP layer (which is stream based).
Each WebSocket message has own framing, so that makes it less sufficient to send streamed data due to need in framing for each message. And onmessage event in browser wont be triggered before whole message will be received. Size of message is defined in framing based on RFC 6455 http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#page-27

Comment: Hi Maksims, 
Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Another question though, i looked into node.js implementation of websockets also, after WCF failed, initially i got the same numbers (data transfer time of around 55 sec for 25MB file), but when i changed the file read method, the numbers drastically changed, so even though "websocket" in itself is a message based protocol, it is possible to have large data streamed quicker as compared to a normal WCF service.

Answer (score 0):

Ohk....
Since WCF didnt work..found out it can be done using ASP.Net 4.5 handlers.